# cross validate selected parameter in a Bayesian model with STAN

Tags: parameters, cross-validation, bayesian, selected, stan

To simplify my problem, I have linear model to fit, y~ Normal(a+b*x,sigma) using STAN. I want to do cross validate the estimated b and sigma only, which means the intercept still needs to be estimated using the validation dataset. However, STAN does not have a cut operation so I do not know how to do this.
Thanks for the help.

The STAN code is as following,

```
data{
  int nTrain;
  int nTest;
  int nBeta;
  matrix[nTrain,nBeta] xTrain;
  matrix[nTest,nBeta] xTest;
  vector[nTrain] yTrain;
  vector[nTest] yTest;
}
parameters{
  vector[nTrain] aTrain;
  vector[nTest] aTest;
  vector[nBeta] b;
  real<lower=0> tau;
}
model{
  yTrain ~ normal(aTrain+XTrain*b,1/tau);
  yTest ~ normal (aTest+XTest*b,1/tau);//I know this statement is wrong because test data inference the estimation of b and tau but do not know how to avoid this in stan
  aTrain~ normal(0,10);
  aTest ~ normal(0,10);
  b ~ normal(0,10);
  tau ~ gamma(0.01,0.01);
}
generated quantities{
 real  yPred[nTest]=normal_rng(aTest+XTest*b,1/tau);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in the end? Stan isn't setup to use cut because of the creators' position that it isn't properly bayesian. There is some info on why here and suggestions of ways to approach cut problems https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2020/01/08/how-to-cut-using-stan-if-you-must/